# Completely Stuck on AJAX Form Submission With Stripe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I am so frustrated. I'm working with Stripe to create a form submission system for payments. Basically, the form makes an AJAX call to Stripe, which gives me a token on success, which I then use to resubmit the form, also through AJAX. If the form is successful, it redirects to a new page, if not, it populates the form with error messages without re-navigation. Here's my form:

```
<%= form_for([@issue, @issue_order]) do |f| %>
  <% if @issue_order.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@issue_order.errors.count, "error") %> occurred. </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @issue_order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% f.hidden_field :issue_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number " %>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV) " %>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration " %>
    <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers_true: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
    <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
  </div>
  <div id="stripe_error"></div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Purchase Issue", id: "submit_issue_order" %></div>
<% end %>
<div class="errors"></div>
```

Here is the javascript that handles the form and sets up the stripe information:

```
var issueOrder;

$(function() {
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
  issueOrder.setupForm();
});

var issueOrder = {
  setupForm: function() {
    $('#new_issue_order').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#submit_issue_order').attr('disabled', true);
      issueOrder.processCard();
      return false;
    });
  },
  processCard: function() {
    var card;
    card = {
      number: $('#card_number').val(),
      cvc: $('#card_code').val(),
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val(),
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    };
    Stripe.createToken(card, issueOrder.handleStripeResponse)
  },
  handleStripeResponse: function(status, response) {
    if (status == 200) {
      $('#issue_order_stripe_card_token').val(response.id);
      // $('#new_issue_order')[0].submit();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $('#new_issue_order').attr('action'),
        data: { "issue_order": {
          "stripe_card_token": $('#issue_order_stripe_card_token').val(),
          "email": $('issue_order_email').val(),
          },
          "issue_id": $('#issue_order_issue_id').val()
        },
        dataType: "script"
      }, issueOrder.processOrder);
    }
    else {
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message);
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
    }
  }
```

And here is my controller:

```
  def create
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => 400,
      :currency => "usd",
      :card => params['issue_order']['stripe_card_token']
    )
    if charge['paid'] == true
      @issue_order = IssueOrder.new(email: params['issue_order']['email'], issue_id: params['issue_id'])
      if @issue_order.save
        @pdf_token = @issue_order.pdf_token
        PdfMailer.pdf_email(params['issue_order']['email'], @issue_order).deliver
      else·
        flash[:error] = []
        flash[:error].push("Your card was charged, but sadly we were unable to create·
        a record in the database. Please contact us for your copy of the issue.")
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js
        end
      end
    else
      # run checks for errors and return error messages
      flash[:error] = []
      flash[:error].push("There was an error in processing your payment.")
      render :json => {success: false}
    end
  end
```

Typical stripe setup stuff. Works fine when the stripe order is successfully processed. Well, it did before I hand-rolled the AJAX call, I'm assuming it'd be fine if I threw a respond_to |format| in the success case in the controller that redirected to the success page. However, for the error cases, my controller renders create.js.erb, which looks like this:

```
console.log('yo');
$('.errors').empty();
errors = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Flash-Error').split(',');
<% flash[:error].each do |error| %>
  $('.errors').append($('<p>' + <%= error %> + '</p>'));
<% end %>
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.errors').empty();
}, 3500);
```

The controller clearly reaches the file and renders it, as evidenced by the logs:

```
Started POST "/issues/1/issue_orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-12 23:33:17 -0500
Processing by IssueOrdersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"issue_order"=>{"stripe_card_token"=>"tok_102vmu2pSkyWUgPAToj334Oa"}, "issue_id"=>"1"}
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered issue_orders/create.js.erb (0.1ms)
["Your card was charged, but sadly we were unable to create \n        a record in the database. Please contact us for your copy of the issue."]
Completed 200 OK in 1363ms (Views: 3.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

But NOTHING happens on my page, including the console log! If I don't hand roll the AJAX and use remote: true, it gets even worse -- it recognizes my submit() call as HTML and doesn't know what to do with the format, rendering an Unknown Format error.

Help!

Comment: Might be me.... but how are you calling the first Ajax call?

Comment: Is `processOrder` defined somewhere else? It's referenced in your posted code but not defined.